# ASP.NET form with two submit buttons not working

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have developed an ASP.NET web site using Visual Studio 2015 and C#. My login page has two sets of username/password/submit controls since it allows for the login of two different kinds of users. In order to make each of the two submit buttons be triggered on hitting Enter, I have put each of the username/password/submit button sets inside an `asp:Panel` control, and designated the default button for the panel through the `DefaultButton` attribute. My code looks like this:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">

    <asp:Panel runat="server" ID="paOne" DefaultButton="buOne">
        <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txOne"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:Button runat="server" ID="buOne" Text="One" OnClick="buOne_Click" />
    </asp:Panel>

    <asp:Panel runat="server" ID="paTwo" DefaultButton="buTwo">
        <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txTwo"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:Button runat="server" ID="buTwo" Text="Two" OnClick="buTwo_Click" />
    </asp:Panel>

    <asp:Label runat="server" ID="laMessage"></asp:Label>

</form>
```

Each panel is rendered on the client as a div having an `onkeypress` event handler set to trigger the corresponding button. The client code looks like this:

```
<form method="post" action="./Default.aspx" id="form1">
    <div class="aspNetHidden">
        <input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE" id="__VIEWSTATE" value="YEhEIVTg9QBY8fOISaQxrzFkXtsZD8oOAvAZ7f6h5Qeh7indHY+rACZRO6ImmbjrGlxUtRWW+BRxFNEO8BjX568tdbIuPRkRzyFhVllP1Zk=" />
    </div>
    <div id="paOne" onkeypress="javascript:return WebForm_FireDefaultButton(event, &#39;buOne&#39;)">
        <input name="txOne" type="text" id="txOne" />
        <input type="submit" name="buOne" value="One" id="buOne" />
    </div>
    <div id="paTwo" onkeypress="javascript:return WebForm_FireDefaultButton(event, &#39;buTwo&#39;)">
        <input name="txTwo" type="text" id="txTwo" />
        <input type="submit" name="buTwo" value="Two" id="buTwo" />
    </div>
    <span id="laMessage"></span>
    <div class="aspNetHidden">
        <input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR" id="__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR" value="CA0B0334" />
        <input type="hidden" name="__EVENTTARGET" id="__EVENTTARGET" value="" />
        <input type="hidden" name="__EVENTARGUMENT" id="__EVENTARGUMENT" value="" />
        <input type="hidden" name="__EVENTVALIDATION" id="__EVENTVALIDATION" value="tSSluQdQzBx1IUSyVs5RBPJDqGj7Ue18MyKgnbEYfUC+1pDL7ofSk6We9GrBbSPsrP85C5UDVNhOv2F4qHTzUFct0OKOWgOMXXmpv6+EFREwJvJWamUmZdRiTbZ1xy+WwXq+5qwM/VIlFKbsYlvcVZAj/GUXCdVL2YfbTPdso1BaSoVXrPSK7hbwr3pagFl+" />
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        //<![CDATA[
        var theForm = document.forms['form1'];
        if (!theForm) {
            theForm = document.form1;
        }
        function __doPostBack(eventTarget, eventArgument) {
            if (!theForm.onsubmit || (theForm.onsubmit() != false)) {
                theForm.__EVENTTARGET.value = eventTarget;
                theForm.__EVENTARGUMENT.value = eventArgument;
                theForm.submit();
            }
        }
        //]]>
    </script>
    <script src="/WebResource.axd?d=pynGkmcFUV13He1Qd6_TZIW5ydMO-N69Qh9Ly_CAmH3SrNlWIPHd8175NakAnLP_S5r9KNXoQHWy_mjBajIxUA2&amp;t=636042734594211026" type="text/javascript"></script>
</form>
```

In my development machine, everything works fine. When I am placed inside the first set of username/password text boxes and I hit Enter, the first submit button is triggered. And like wise for the second set.

However, when I deploy my web site to my production server (IIS 7 on Windows Server 2008), this stops working. Regardless of where I am located in the form, the first submit button is triggered when I hit Enter, as if the javascript event handlers are ignored. Why is this happening? How can I fix it? Thanks.

UPDATE. I know why the problem occurs, although I don't know how to fix it. As you can see in the client code above, single quotes in the `WebForm_FireDefaultButton` call are being escaped as ' codes, rendering the call argument incorrect. Why does IIS 7 do this?

UDPATE 2. Thanks to @VDWWD for providing [this pointer](https://forums.asp.net/p/1554455/3818604.aspx) where an apparent bug in .NET 4 is described. Apparently, .NET 4 encodes attributes added from the server side so that single quotes are escaped, which breaks things.

Comment: Could you provide a [minimal verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of the issue?

Comment: Can you show the generated HTML?

Comment: I am showing now server and client code. I have also added an update on why the problem happens,

Answer (score 1):

You are close, the `Panel` Control had a `DefaultButton` property. You can assign the correct button that will be fired when pressing enter.

```
<asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server" DefaultButton="Button1">
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" ValidationGroup="Login1"></asp:TextBox>
    <br />
    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" ErrorMessage="This field is required" ControlToValidate="TextBox1" ValidationGroup="Login1"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
    <br />
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Login 1" OnClick="Button1_Click" ValidationGroup="Login1" />
</asp:Panel>

<asp:Panel ID="Panel2" runat="server" DefaultButton="Button2">
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" ValidationGroup="Login2"></asp:TextBox>
    <br />
    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator2" runat="server" ErrorMessage="This field is required" ControlToValidate="TextBox2" ValidationGroup="Login2"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
    <br />
    <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="Login 2" OnClick="Button2_Click" ValidationGroup="Login2" />
</asp:Panel>
```

Comment: Well, I forgot to say that I am actually using the `DefaultButton` attribute as you indicate. Sorry that I didn't say it before. I have updated my OP now.

Comment: Replacing `'` with `&#39;` is normal behavior. But I cannot reproduce your error. I copied your code but it works as expected... Is there something in `buOne_Click` and/or `buTwo_Click`

Comment: No, ' should not be replaced with &#39; within javascript code. Look for example at `'form1'` in the OP. The `buOne_Click` and `buTwo_Click` simply display each a message on screen so that you know which one has been clicked.

Comment: I ment normal behaviour for asp.net. I know it should be a `'`. See https://forums.asp.net/p/1554455/3818604.aspx for a similar discussion.

Comment: According to the post that you mention, this way of encoding in .NET 4 it seems to be a bug rather than "normal behaviour" :-) It definitely breaks things. Also, why is it happening in my production server but not in my development machine?

Comment: Good question. I don't know. asp.net does this on my local and production servers and I've never had any issues with it so I just took it for granted I guess.

Comment: Well, lucky you! ;-)